# Foreign key does not display on phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm trying to add a foreign key constraint on a table using phpmyadmin.

The SQL query succeed but the constraint does not appear on the tab, nor is usable when I try to insert a new field.
However I can see the constraint when I execute `SHOW TABLE my_table`, and the constraint also appear when I add the foreign key using Adminer with a copy of the database locally.

I can also add a foreign key on a different table and it display correctly.

Do I need to check something up on my table configuration ?

Comment: Just below the `Structure` tab, there is a `Relation view` button. This button location might differ by version, but I have v4.6.5.2.  [example image](https://imgbox.com/5F0eGI7f)

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense because if a constraint exists properly, it should be enforced by MySQL/MariaDB regardless of how you're accessing the database (command-line client, phpMyAdmin, or Adminer). The fact that the constraint doesn't affect when you insert a new field suggests to me that the constraint isn't properly formed or wasn't created. Could you share more information about how you created the constraint?